# Cannot figure out what my "unexpected error" is in my R-code

Tags: r

```
barplot('AOWinner')Championdata$year,Championdata$Ctry_Champion,x;xlab='Year'ylab='Nationality'
```

my error shows

> Error: unexpected symbol in "barplot('AOWinner')Championdata

Comment: The string `'AOWinner'` seems out of place, and similarly the `;`

Comment: can you explain what you mean by the string 'AOwinner' is out of place

Comment: What you are trying to do iis `barplot("A")` where you are assuming "A" is an object, but it is just a string and doesn't have any value

Comment: can you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to do? Your *proximal* problem is that after a close-parenthesis `)` R expects to see a semicolon or a line break (or something, but not a letter), but the code here isn't doing to do anything sensible even if you put a semicolon after the parenthesis ...

Comment: @BenBolker I am trying to create a plot (a barplot more so) from a dataset that shows the amount of times a country has won a certain tennis tournament

Answer (score 1):

try to understand how `barplot()` works.

You need to get your data into the right shape to have it plotted.

```
# simulate some tournament data
Championdata <- data.frame(
   year = c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
 , Ctry_Champion = c("Italy","Germany","Italy","Switzerland","Italy")
)

# produce a table of counts
# in R you can do this by "tabling" your data variable
counts <- table(Championdata$Ctry_Champion)

# check out what you have done:
counts
```

```
    Germany       Italy Switzerland 
          1           3           1
```

With this we can make barplot show the counts:

```
# then inject this into barplot
barplot(counts)
```

You can then add your labels etc to your liking.
But this would be the way forward with your problem.

[image]